# How to Handle Race Condition Due to AsyncTask android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a listview control which is updated in the following sequence

a) Activity gets a broadcast event, which is handled in onRecieve

b) An AsyncTask is started , In doBackground which would read a file and populate an temporary array which would be passed to postExecute. In post execute a array myArray which backs the adapter for listview is updated by data passed. And Adapter notifychanged is called

Now, There is also a function where user can check the rows in listview and click a button say remove. This will remove the entries from the array (myArray).

The problem: As button press and AsyncTask can happen at any time, How to maintain a sequencing, so that when remove button is pressed the listview is not refreshed.

Comment: How about disabling the button using `button.setEnabled(false)` for the duration of AsyncTask. Would that work alright? Or does the AsyncTask take considerable time and may affect UX.

Answer (score 0):

Since `onClickListener` and `onPostExecute` are executed on the main thread you can cancel the async task when the button pressed. In this case `onPostExecute` wouldn't executed if it hasn't executed yet.